# Altbeacon android beacon library not working after device has screen off for a substantial time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon, eddystone

Android Beacon Library version: `2.16.2`

Devices issues are occurring on: Samsung 8.1, Samsung 8.0, Samsung 7.1.1

I am having issues where the Altbeacon library is not detecting beacons for 30, 40, 50, all the way up to 1000 seconds. This seems to only occur when the screen is off.

Android-Manifest

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Here is my creation of the beaconManager, it is inside of a foreground service that is on persistently.

```
private fun createBeaconMgr() {
        BeaconManager.setDebug(true)
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)

        if (!beaconManager.scheduledScanJobsEnabled)
        {
            beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(true)

        }
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.apply {
            add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
            add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT))
            add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT))
        }



        beaconManager.bind(this)

    }
```

This is my beaconServiceConnect, and other overrides.

```
    override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        if (beaconManager.rangingNotifiers.isNotEmpty() && beaconManager.monitoringNotifiers.isNotEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        //TODO: Dynamically build identifiers and regions

        beaconManager.foregroundScanPeriod = 1100
        beaconManager.foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0

        beaconManager.updateScanPeriods()

        try {
            //Start looking for Beacons
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beacon1Region)
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beacon2Region)
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beacon3Region)
            //Start range finding beacons
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beacon1Region)
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beacon2Region)
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beacon3Region)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.message!!)
        }

        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this)
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this)
    }

    override fun didEnterRegion(region: Region) {
        //possibly temporarily added. Issues occured before this, and this was a solution we tried
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beacon1Region)
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beacon2Region)
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beacon3Region)
    }

    override fun didExitRegion(region: Region) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Did exit")
    }

    override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(state: Int, region: Region) {
        Log.d(TAG, "did determine")
    }

    override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(beacons: Collection<Beacon>, region: Region) {

        val dateRead = Date() //this is logged to our database

        //business logic below
}
```

Below is a logcat from a specific time where it did not detect a beacon, even though I left one sitting on top of the tablet (It did not detect it for ~26 seconds). Upon request, I can provide more of the logs.

```
Processing pdu type FF: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 26, endIndex: 31

[ 09-17 15:15:10.924  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.925  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.925  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.925  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.925  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.926  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:10.928 24172:24461 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.928 24172:24461 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.923 24172: 3828 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:10.929 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:10.943  2565: 3188 D/libgps   ]
OnGpsExtensionMessage: message_id(1), data(0x7b0b2038), size(3336)


[ 09-17 15:15:10.944  2565: 3188 D/libgps   ]
proxy__gnss_sv_status_cb: called. num_svs(2)

[ 09-17 15:15:10.944  2565: 3188 D/GnssLocationProvider_ex ]
SV Count : 2(0) / TOP5(v) : 27 17  / TOP5(u) : 

[ 09-17 15:15:10.957  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.958  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.958  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.958  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.958  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.958  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.958  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:10.959 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.959 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.959 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:10.968  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.968  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.969  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.969  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.969  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.969  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.971  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:10.972 24172:24184 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.972 24172:24184 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.972 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:10.989  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.989  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.989  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.989  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:10.989  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.989  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.990  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:10.991 24172:24461 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:10.991 24172:24461 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:10.991 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:10.992 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 30

[ 09-17 15:15:10.992 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 2 and 10 at offset 4.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:10.992 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 30

[ 09-17 15:15:10.992 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.019  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.019  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.019  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.019  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.019  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.019  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.025  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:11.029  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.029  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.029  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.029  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.029  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.029  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.030 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScanner ]
Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 100 milliseconds

[ 09-17 15:15:11.035  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.035  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.036  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.036  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.036  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.036  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.044 24172: 3826 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 1bff75004204018060c048e6fa643dc248e6fa643c016f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 27

[ 09-17 15:15:11.045 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 26 and 10 at offset 28.  The bytes I see are: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 08

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 07

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 26, endIndex: 31

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 08

[ 09-17 15:15:11.046 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 07

[ 09-17 15:15:11.047 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 26, endIndex: 31

[ 09-17 15:15:11.047 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 26 and 00 at offset 28.  The bytes I see are: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.047 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.047 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 08

[ 09-17 15:15:11.047 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 07

[ 09-17 15:15:11.047 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 26, endIndex: 31

[ 09-17 15:15:11.048 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 26 and 20 at offset 28.  The bytes I see are: 0201060208001107757ed3e418284a0c8362c229c3a6da7207ff88c6267c6901000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.048 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c000c0e007082d2b06a4412c1d208efdf4a10050b1c24d3bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.048 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.048 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c000c0e007082d2b06a4412c1d208efdf4a10050b1c24d3bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29

[ 09-17 15:15:11.049 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 00 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c000c0e007082d2b06a4412c1d208efdf4a10050b1c24d3bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.049 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.049 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c000c0e007082d2b06a4412c1d208efdf4a10050b1c24d3bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29

[ 09-17 15:15:11.049 24172: 3829 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 20 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c000c0e007082d2b06a4412c1d208efdf4a10050b1c24d3bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.056  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.057  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.057  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.057  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.057  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.057  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.061  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:11.061  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:11.061  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:11.062 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.062 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 30

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2565:24988 D/LocationManagerService ]
getProviders()=[gps]

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2565:24988 D/LocationManagerService ]
getBestProvider(Criteria[power=NO_REQ acc=HIGH], true)=gps

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.063 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 2 and 00 at offset 4.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.064  2943: 4306 D/BtGatt.ContextMap ]
sendClientScanResult for app id 6

[ 09-17 15:15:11.065 20589:20612 D/DriverLocationManager ]
getBestProvider: gps

[ 09-17 15:15:11.066  2565: 3565 D/LocationManagerService ]
getLastLocation: Request[ACCURACY_FINE gps requested=0 fastest=0 num=1]

[ 09-17 15:15:11.045 24172: 3828 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 0201060aff4c0010050b1cf8e6ef000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.066 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 30

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 2 and 20 at offset 4.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002d94a4a4a79d87c0805372dedc5569f4b9b9bdd4f4fcbdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 10 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 20589:20612 I/com.changedName.android.obuservices.ScreenBlockService ]
Speed:0

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14

[ 09-17 15:15:11.067 20589:20612 I/com.changedName.android.obuservices.ScreenBlockService ]
check driving status: false0

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 10 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 00 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.068 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 14

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 00 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 20 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011b0bff4c00090603000a010ae10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.069 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c0010051a1cbc5298000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 20 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c001005131c09b535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172:24185 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 10 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c0010051a1cbc5298000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.070 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c0010051a1cbc5298000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c0010051a1cbc5298000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
with service uuid: 00001122-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Ignoring pdu type 01

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172:24172 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop ]
got record

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
first manudata for manu ID

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172: 3830 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c000c0e007082d2b06a4412c1d208efdf4a10050b1c24d3bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071 24172: 3827 D/BeaconParser ]
Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c0010051a1cbc5298000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
Not a Multi Manu data

[ 09-17 15:15:11.071  2943: 3063 D/ScanRecord ]
parseFromBytes
```

Any ideas?

```
Set up a scan filter: BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null, mUuid=null, mUuidMask=null, mServiceDataUuid=null, mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=118, mManufacturerData=BE AC, mManufacturerDataMask=FF FF]

[ 09-17 17:34:43.831  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
making scan filter for service: 0000FEAA-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

[ 09-17 17:34:43.831  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
making scan filter with service mask: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff

[ 09-17 17:34:43.831  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
Set up a scan filter: BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null, mUuid=0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, mUuidMask=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff, mServiceDataUuid=null, mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=ffffffff, mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null]

[ 09-17 17:34:43.832  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
making scan filter for service: 0000FEAA-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

[ 09-17 17:34:43.832  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
making scan filter with service mask: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff

[ 09-17 17:34:43.832  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
Set up a scan filter: BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null, mUuid=0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, mUuidMask=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff, mServiceDataUuid=null, mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=ffffffff, mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null]

[ 09-17 17:34:43.833  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
making scan filter for service: 0000FEAA-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

[ 09-17 17:34:43.833  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
making scan filter with service mask: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff

[ 09-17 17:34:43.833  7169: 7392 D/ScanFilterUtils ]
Set up a scan filter: BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null, mUuid=0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, mUuidMask=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff, mServiceDataUuid=null, mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=ffffffff, mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null]
```

Comment: I suspect the issue has to do with a scan filter that does not match.  Please look for a log lines similar to below after you put your app to the background. and add themt to your question or in a comment here.  (You  should see 3-4 different log lines like this since you add three beacon parsers).  `D/ScanFilterUtils: Set up a scan filter: BluetoothLeScanFilter
[mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null,
mUuid=0000fe6a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,
mUuidMask=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff, mServiceDataUuid=null,
mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=ffffffff`
`

Comment: Hi David, updated the post with the requested data.

This is happening in our office environment, I have two beacons in range always, why would it not detect them? There might be other devices broadcasting around our office, but it should always detect 2. 

It detects them when the screen is on, why would turning the screen off matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that due to my 2 way authentication method, some of the logs were not making it into the API, but no logs showed up because it is at the TLS level.

Querying the on device DB turned up 3.5 million logs, so there was no issue with android beacon library

Comment: Glad that you found the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help! Greatly appreciated! If your in SF, I'll buy you a beer.

Answer (score 1):

When the screen is off, Samsung devices with Android 8.1+ require that non-empty BLE scan filters be used or no BLE packets can be detected.  The Android Beacon Library is aware of this, so it sets up scan filters for each BeaconParser you have active so that

For some reason, these ScanFilters shown in your question appear to not be matching the packets you are expecting despite the fact that they look good.  Why?  One possible answer is that your device has run out of ScanFilters -- each one requires a slot on the bluetooth chip and there are a limited number of slots available to *all* apps on your phone.  Here are some things you can try to see if that is the case:

1. Clear out the default beacon parser (for AltBeacon) since you are not using it with `BeaconParser().clear()`
2. Try adding only *ONE* beacon parser (instead of the three shown) and test to see if just that beacon type is detected with the screen off.
3. If (1) and (2) do not help, reboot your phone and try again.  This may clear beacon parsers that are stuck.
4. If none of the above help, try uninstalling other apps that you think might be doing bluetooth beacon scans and tying up the limited number of ScanFilter slots on the bluetooth chip, then reboot and try again.

Comment: So I'm testing the above. 

It isn't that it never works with the screen off, its that it doesn't work after ~1 hour. 

Plot of the time between each detection in seconds.  https://imgur.com/a/gOthiyw

After the installation of a new version, put the app in the background and set the tablet aside with the screen off. 

All of the tablets are factory wiped, so nothing but the stock samsung installed apps.

I've also got the entire logcat from last night (1.8gb text file) I can share...

Answer (score 0):

As of Android N, scans of 30 min or more are blocked in the background.  You can force a workaround when using the Android Beacon Library by adding this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService"
             tools:node="replace">
        <meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>
</service>
```

Comment: I already have that. Please check my answer, there was no issue with the library